# I can't undersrand how to divide with brackets and input results

Tags: python, math

```
BaseLength = int ( input ("Enter Base Length") )
BaseWidth = int ( input ("Enter A Base Width: ")
PyramidHeight: = int ( input ("Enter Pyramid Height: ")

print (int ( BaseLength*BaseWidth*PyramidHeight/3))
```

How do I use the `input` results in the equation? I am just starting and also young, please be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

A couple of missing brackets and such, first fix:

```
BaseLength = int ( input ("Enter Base Length: ") )
BaseWidth = int ( input ("Enter A Base Width: ") )
PyramidHeight = int ( input ("Enter Pyramid Height: ") )

print(int ( BaseLength*BaseWidth*PyramidHeight/3))
```

Note that in particular the second and third lines of code are missing a bracked: the int() function is opened but never closed, which Python was likely complaining about.

Also the int() cast at the end will round down the result of your expression: e.g. `int((1*1*1)/3) = int(0.33333...) = 0` (to force the result to be an integer (round number) and not a number with decimals). That's probably not what you want here. You can let Python handle the formatting here:

```
BaseLength = int ( input ("Enter Base Length: ") )
BaseWidth = int ( input ("Enter A Base Width: ") )
PyramidHeight = int ( input ("Enter Pyramid Height: ") )

print(BaseLength*BaseWidth*PyramidHeight/3)
```

Let me know if you have any issues. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much! One small issue with the code is that I want decimals in the final result.

Comment: see the updated answer, I just realised that myself :)